# How can I share my Ganache workspace with someone else?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, truffle, ganache

I'm developing a dapp using Ganache/Truffle. The problem is that other elements of the team don't have acess to my ganache accounts (private and public) and vice-versa.

Is there any way where we can all acess the same accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Boas.

Ganache is really geared towards local development and considerations about your local network are not really priority.

You have several options for team development.

1) You can use Dockerfile with this image : https://hub.docker.com/r/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/. Setup your configurations and scripts, and share that with your team. I assume you are probably using truffle, so truffle.js (config truffle) should also be configured to setup default accounts, networks, etc.

2) If you want something more rudimentary, you can use ngrok (https://ngrok.com/) to port forward your localhost into the open web for people to access it. I've used this with  other apps, but haven't test it with ganache.

3) Give Kaleido a try (kaleido.io). They have free accounts, they support GETH & QUORUM and you can create access credentials for your team mates to use if you want.